# »gen Mekka beten«

Tags: preposition

Im Roman *Tschick* von Wolfgang Herrndorf, fand ich diesen Satz:

> Ich könnte noch gen Mekka beten

Das Wort "gen" hatte ich nie vorher gekannt. Es benutzt ein vierzehnjähriger Protagonist eines Romans, der 2012 erschien. Und dieser Junge spricht immer ziemlich informell.

Aber bei dict.leo.org finde ich diesen Eintrag:

> gen +acc. dated

Wenn es ein ausgedientes Wort ist, dann erwarte ich nicht, dass so ein Junge es benutzen würde.

Wie is die Wahrheit?

Comment: _"gen Mekka beten"_ ist eine fixe Phrase.

Comment: So wie die Kommentare bereits andeuten, scheint es eine fixe Phrase der Jugendsprache zu sein. Um beurteilen zu können, ob die Bedeutung der Phrase hier passt, müsste man etwas mehr Kontext aus dem Roman kennen.

Comment: @IQV Der Satz ist ziemlich am Anfang, deswegen hier die [Leseprobe mit dem Zitat auf Seite 12](https://www.rowohlt.de/fm/131/Herrndorf_Tschick.pdf). Obwohl vom Kontext her (Hauptperson befindet sich als Beschuldigter auf Polizeiwache in schlechtem körperlichem Zustand) sowohl die religiöse, als auch die jugendsprachliche Auslegung möglich sind halte ich hier die Interpretation mit "sich übergeben" (siehe Link von @tofro) für wahrscheinlicher. Hat allerdings keine Auswirkung auf den Kern der Frage über die Verwendung und Häufigkeit des Wortes gen :) .

Comment: @mtwde Danke für die Quelle. Aber ich glaube schon, dass das für den Kern der Frage entscheidend ist. Ich bezweifle, dass solch ein Jugendlicher die Bedeutung von "gen" tatsächlich kennt und das Wort aktiv nutzt. Er kennt vielleicht die fixe Phrase und ihre Bedeutung, ohne allerdings die Bestandteile der Phrase wirklich zu verstehen.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Gen Mekka beten* mag eine feste Phrase sein, aber die Himmelsrichtungen werden auch heute noch gerne mit der Präposition *gen* verwendet.

> Blicken wir also gen Osten.

Damit ist dann aber nicht die Himmelsrichtung gemeint, sondern irgendetwas, was grob in diese Richtung liegt. Also, z.B. Polen, Ukraine, Russland.